# Are there libraries for capacitive touch sensors in Eagle?

Tags: capacitive-sensor

I want to use a capacitive touch sensor, specifically a wheel-type sensor, like the one shown below:

[image]

However, it's been a real headache as I've tried various ways to draw it, but I haven't found the right method to import it correctly into Eagle 9.4. I was thinking that someone might have a library I could use, or perhaps a guide or information to create it myself?

Note: I tried to follow the steps indicated on [this page](https://bryanduxbury.com/2013/12/05/designing-a-capacitive-touch-wheel-in-openscad-and-eagle/), but I ended up even more confused because I couldn't get it to work on my PC.